# Utilizing MMX with Managed C++

Tags: .net, c++, clr, unmanaged, managed

From what I understand, the JIT does not compile the MSIL into native machine code that will utilize MMX instructions on x86.  If this is true (as I'm having a hard time finding up to date information on the matter), then I want a way to utilize MMX in my code.  I am working on an application that will be doing almost all single precision floating point number multiplication (it's artificial neural networks).  I basically have several questions around the matter.

My first is, if I mix managed and unmanaged code in the same project, isn't it all compiled into MSIL because "It Just Works"?  Would I get the best performance if I made the unmanaged parts as static or dynamic libraries, compiled them, and used them in my managed project?

I have also looked into using my GPU with OpenCL (or CUDA, but then it wouldn't work on ATI :(  ) but if I was to do that, wouldn't the compiled GPU code have to be called from unmanaged c++?

Over all, I am just looking for the best way to get the fastest floating point arthmitic while still being able to use my managed GUI and Multithreading and using extensions like MMX seem to be my best option (if I only want to use the CPU).  What is the best way there may be to go about doing such a thing?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for your question, but I wonder if you might not improve the neural network algorithm or its use, to improve performance?  You may very well need more speed, but I ask because I have seen many neural network projects suffer from poor neural architecture, over-exploration of parameters, weak data design, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MMX is an integer instruction set, not floating point.  It only supports 64-bit packed byte, word and double-word integers.  SSE has floating point support.  Use #pragma managed in your code to switch between machine code and MSIL generation.

Answer (score 0):

you can mix managed and unmanaged code.    Only the managed is compiled to MSIL.   The rest is native.

There is a cost going between managed and unmanaged....but not too bad.

So I'd write a native lib that did all your high performance stuff and then use it from your managed code.

Answer (score 0):

> My first is, if I mix managed and unmanaged code in the same project, isn't it all compiled into MSIL because "It Just Works"

No.  If you don't compile with `/clr:pure`, native code can stay native and be mixed in with .NET code.  This is called a mixed-mode assembly.  (With `/clr:pure`, everything is turned into IL, and you can't use native code at all.)  Native code will stay native.